# array format for D3 streamgraph

Tags: javascript, graph, d3.js, stream-graph

https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Stack-Layout

http://mbostock.github.com/d3/ex/stream.html

[image]

I'm trying to make a streamgraph with D3.js. Looking at the example, we see that the data is formulated through the helper function `stream_layers(n, m)`. In this example an array is returned as described in the API. The API describes input x, y and y0. But the example uses x, y0, y1.

My dataset is formulated similarly to the one described in the API:

```
{
    "name": "apples",
    "values": [
      { "year": -2000, "y":  91},
      { "year": -1950, "y": 290}
 ]
},
{  
  "name": "oranges",
  "values": [
    { "year": -2000, "y":  9},
    { "year": -1950, "y": 49}
  ]
}
```

What would a helper function that stacks this dataset look like? The example returns a 3D array (one dimension for the number of layers, one for the number of samples `m` and one for the y-values at each sample).

Comment: Possibly helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11009524/how-to-use-stack-valuesaccessor-in-d3-js-streamgraph